# Integer value of a character in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am looking to turn the character 'a' into 97 in ruby 1.9.2

Ruby 1.8.7

```
irb(main):001:0> ?a
=> 97
```

Ruby 1.9.2

```
irb(main):001:0> ?a
=> "a"
```

Comment: This link will help with other changes in 1.9 also : http://eigenclass.org/hiki/Changes+in+Ruby+1.9#l16

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You probably want [`String#ord`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/String.html#method-i-ord):

```
% irb
ruby-1.9.2-head > 'a'.ord
 => 97
```

Answer (score 37):

For those, who are looking for the opposite of `ord`. We have `chr`

```
>> "A".ord
=> 65
>> 65.chr
=> "A"
```

Comment: Great - I needed this exactly, to add a gtk-entry that can be toggled by the user, for scrambling/ciphering the alphabet.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you want to write code that is compatible with *both* Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9, you may want to use [`String#each_byte`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-each_byte) like this:

```
$ irb
>> 'a'.each_byte.first
=> 97
```

Comment: That is useful to know. I think .ord and .chr are more reliable for the future, though.

Answer (score -2):

`?a` will return the ASCII value of the char a

Comment: Sadly, '?c' will not work same as pre-Ruby 1.9. See http://eigenclass.org/hiki/Changes+in+Ruby+1.9#l16

Comment: `?a` will return the closest thing to a `char` type Ruby has, which in Ruby 1.9 is a single-character `String` and in Ruby pre-1.9 is a `Fixnum`. `String#ord` (and its dual `Integer#chr`) is what you want to use.